# Is it possible to setup google CDN for an external wordpress website?

Tags: wordpress, kubernetes, google-cloud-platform, google-cdn

I have a website that is developed by WordPress. Recently I try to activate Google CDN for this website. My host provider is not google. After installing CDN it takes almost 3 hours to activate SSL. I replaced the IP that I created in A record of the website. I get this error :

```
ERR_TOO_MANY_REDIRECT
```

I disabled all plugins and rename .htaccess. But I read an article in TargetTrend website which was published one years ago that says:

> If you are not hosting your site with Google Cloud Platform (GCP), you
> will be unable to use Google Cloud CDN. This is because Google Cloud
> CDN only works with Google load balancer and cloud storage origin.

Do you try to use Google CDN for your WordPress website which is not hosted by google cloud?

**UPDATED: Adding the process I followed.**

To make my question more clear I follow these steps:

1. I did not have google cloud account, so I signed up.
2. Network services >> Cloud CDN - In this they ask me to enable cloud engine and I enable that, later
   again I return to : *Network services >> Cloud CDN*
3. I click on *Add Origin*.
4. I set a name, and I choose *customer origin*, as *IP
   address/Domain Name* I type example.nl and *Port* 80
5. I click on *Create new load balancer for me*  and type
   *my-nl-website*
6. under *Custom request headers* , I clicked on Add header, *Host*
   as  *header name*, and *example.nl* as *header value 1* and click on    *DONE*
7. I went to Network service >> Load Balancer, here I clicked on the
   *my-nl-website* , there was an IP, I copy this IP and add an extra A record  for this IP
8. Later  I get error on `this website is not secure` and I edited the load balancer, I creat a new IP and clicked on google certificate, and wait until SSL created.
9. Now instead of getting the website is not secure, I get *redirect to many times.*
10. Currently based on what I read in the Document, I try to create a *load balancer* and *network endpoint group* manually and then try *cloud CDN*.  I hope this manual creation solves my problem.

Comment: Too many redirects issue is often caused by the proxy/load balancer performing SSL termination and WordPress is not configured to process the **HTTP_X_FORWARDED_FOR** HTTP header. Use the CLI tool **curl** to debug responses from your endpoint. Edit your question to show how you have configured Cloud CDN.

Comment: Thanks @JohnHanley for the time you spent reading my problem. I updated it and I added the process I followed.

Comment: From your question, it looks like you configured **two** IP addresses for the load balancer? That will **not** work. Use the same IP address for both the HTTP and HTTPS frontends. Delete the HTTP frontend and recreate using the same IP address as the HTTPS frontend. Also delete the extra A record.

Answer (score 2):

Yes, you can use the Cloud CDN with **external** original also.

we were running it before and moved WordPress to GKE for redirect SSL error try adding snippet into `config.php` once, plus make sure inside database `wp_option or wp_setting` table have site URL are using **HTTPS** not **HTTP**

```
if ( isset( $_SERVER['HTTP_X_FORWARDED_PROTO'] ) && 'https' == $_SERVER['HTTP_X_FORWARDED_PROTO'] ) {
    $_SERVER['HTTPS'] = 'on';
}
```

in cloud CDN you have options for `backend service`, `cloud bucket` and `custom origin` also.

[image]

Ref document : https://cloud.google.com/cdn/docs/setting-up-cdn-with-ex-backend-internet-neg

Comment: Thanks for your help, Should I `add a new` A record for the IP I get in Load Balancer in DNS, or do I have to `replace` it with the IP of the Host?

Comment: @M.SallarRabiei - Your question implies that you are **not** using a load balancer. Edit your question to clarify what you have configured.

Comment: @JohnHanley As I notice, after clicking on enable CDN, google cloud creates two sections: load balancer and network endpoint group. I do not touch them, they are created automatically.

Comment: For WordPress, the configuration file is **wp-config.php**. You mentioned **config.php**.

Comment: @M.SallarRabiei - even though they are created for you, you still must configure them correctly.